# jquery function works after single space in quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am learning jQuery and new to it. I was trying to run some code but it was not running and then I found that I just need to give one space before ending double commas/quotes "

```
$("div:not([id=header]) " + strWhichTag).each(function(){
    //some function          
});
```

Now the question is that **why do we need to give space after id=header])** if I remove that space and use this code, it doesn't work, the code below doesn't work but Why

```
$("div:not([id=header])" + strWhichTag).each(function(){
    //some function          
});
```

CHANGES------------------------
strWhichTag is basically h3 but it is not child to #header

**Second thing I need to know is this**

```
var oList = $("<ul id='bookmarksList'>");
```

here can I use single quotes and double quotes alternatively or  I need to keep the same level like using double quotes and use sigle quotes inside them

I am learning it so any help will be appriciated

Comment: Look at the result of `"div:not([id=header])" + strWhichTag`.

Comment: strWhcihTag is basically h3 tags on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say

```
var strWhichTag = 'span';

$("div:not([id=header])" + strWhichTag)
```

evaluates to `$("div:not([id=header])span")` // No tag where `div` and `span` are equivalent

But if the same is `$("div:not([id=header]) span")` .. It will try to find all the spans inside the `div tag which does not have given id`

Comment: Yes i got it know, great work, yes strWhichTag was actually h3 so it would become $("div:not([id=header]) h3"), now i got the meaning of it

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 5):

**First question**

The jQuery's argument is a CSS selector.

The space means that you are selecting a child of `div:not([id=header])`;

```
"div:not([id=header]) div#foo"
```

is not the same as

```
"div:not([id=header])div#foo"
```

---

**Second question:**

The "hierarchy" of quotes doesn't matter, `"text'foo'dd"` is OK, just as `'text"foo"dd'`.

It's up to your taste, but usually using single quotes outside is more practical, since you can have the double ones, used most of the time, in the string.

Comment: Actually i am trying to get each strWhichTag (h3 tag) but excluding any h3 tags inside #header div So strWhichTag (h3 tags) are not children of #header

Comment: well that was the meaning of a space. Obviously, with some strWhichTag's, it can have different meaning, but a space in a selector is important anyway.

Comment: Yes i got it know that the space is for separating the next coming selector or whatever was there

Comment: OK then you can accept this, I think I answered what you've asked.

Comment: I already accepted another one but gave your comment one point up

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what `strWhichTag` but let assume it is a string like `.class`

without space, you arent looking a `div` that is not `#header` and with the class `class`.

```
<div class='class'></div>
```

This would be ok.

With a space, you are looking for an element with class `class` inside a `div` not `#header`.

```
<div><img class='class' /></div>
```

Here, it would select the `img`.